# Can not pass parameters to silverlight appllication with disabled _sl_historyFrame

Tags: c#, silverlight, navigation

I disabled `_sl_historyFrame` in `aspx` page to prevent Back/Forward navigation. Now I found that i can't pass parameters to application like this: http://contoso.com:7553/Page.aspx#/Sub/1/2.

I get empty Url on `NavigationFrame_OnNavigating` method.

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: There are workarounds to prevent Back/Forward navigation http://mrpanot.wordpress.com/2010/05/19/prevent-browser-back-button-for-silverlight-with-confirm-dialog/, but it's desireable to not to change existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by passing `initParams` parameter to an silverlight object in aspx page.

Page.aspx

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2">
    <param name="splashscreensource" value="SplashScreen.xaml" />
    <%
      string value = String.Empty;
      // take parameters from QueryString
      foreach (string key in Request.QueryString.Keys)
      {
        value += String.Format("{0}={1},", key, Request.QueryString.Get(key));
      }

      Response.Write(String.Format("<param name=\"initParams\" value=\"{0}\"/>", value));
      // it writes <param name="initParams" value="id=1,var1=2,var2=3"
    %>
    <%-- another parameters --%>
 </object>
```

In `ApplicationStartup` method I handle like this

```
private void ApplicationStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
     // some code...
     if (e.InitParams != null)
     {
          // process our parameters
          // example of getting: e.InitParams["ID"]
     }
}
```

Some links:

- http://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-pass-parameters-into-silverlight.html
- http://jesseliberty.com/2008/12/26/passing-parameters-into-silverlight-applications/